# Saving drawn layer and updating the layer switcher without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3.9 draw feature to create layers and save them in a PostgreSQL database and publishing them using geoserver so I can use the WMS to display the saved layers.

Whenever the map page is loaded I am generating the following javascript file using a php script which runs a loop and defines all the existing layers (like drw1, drw2, .. ) to get the layers from geoserver and I use `ol3-layerswitcher` to list all the layers that are loaded.

```
var drw1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'draw_test_1',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/TEST/wms',
            params:{
                'LAYERS': 'draw_test_1',
                'TILED': true
            },
            serverType: 'geoserver'
        })),
});
```

Currently, I am refreshing the map page whenever a new layer is saved so that the js file gets updated and the new layer will be added and gets displayed in layerswitcher.

I want to save the layer and refresh the layer switcher without reloading the map. I tried using ajax to save the layer and update the js file in background and adding the updated js file again.

```
<script>
    $('#savelayer').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'savelyr.php',
            data: 'slyrname='+$('#slyrname').val()+'&getdrawn='+$('#getdrawn').val(),
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: 'maplayers.php',
            success: function() {
                var s1 = document.createElement("script");
                s1.src = "src/ol/map.js";
                s1.innerHTML = null;
                document.getElementById("scripts").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("scripts").appendChild(s1);
                console.log("Success 2");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The js file gets updated and is being added to the map page but I am not sure how to update the layer switcher to show the new layer in the list. I believe that the renderPanel() function in ol3-layerswitcher auto updates the list every time it's closed and opened. But it doesn't seem to work.

So I think the problem is with the way I am adding the js file after saving. Can someone let me know where the problem is or what I need to do to get the layer switcher updated without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of struggle trying to figure out what the problem is I gave up and modified my code like this. This just defines the new layer and adds it to the map and layer switcher.

```
    var num = 0;
    var tmp = "tmp"+num;
    var s = "s"+num;

    $('#savelayer').click(function() {
        var slyrname = $('#slyrname').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'savelyr.php',
            data: 'slyrname='+$('#slyrname').val()+'&getdrawn='+$('#getdrawn').val(),
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'map.php',
                    success: function() {
                        var s = document.createElement("script");
                        s.innerHTML = 
                        "var "+tmp+" = new ol.layer.Tile({"+
                            "title: '"+slyrname+"',"+
                            "source: new ol.source.TileWMS({"+
                            "url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WS/wms',"+
                            "params:{'Layers':'"+slyrname+"'}}),"+
                            "zIndex:'1'});";
                        document.getElementById("scripts").appendChild(s);
                        map.addLayer(tmp);
                        num++;
                        console.log("Success 2");
                    }
                });
            }
        }); 
    });
```

A better approach can still be useful.